# Covariance of dependent random variables from a Poisson process

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

**Question:** Given a Poisson process $N(t),t≥0$ with rate $λ$, calculate the covariance of $N(2)$ and $N(3)$.

**Attempt:** So clearly $N(2) \sim Po(2\lambda)$ and $N(3) \sim Po(3\lambda)$.
So, $\mathbb{E}(N(2))=2\lambda$ and $\mathbb{E}(N(3))=3\lambda$.

We know $Cov(N(2),N(3))=\mathbb{E}(N(2)N(3))-\mathbb{E}(N(2))\mathbb{E}(N(3))$

Now, I saw somewhere that $\mathbb{E}(N(2)N(3))=\mathbb{E}(N(2)\mathbb{E}(N(3)|N(2))$ but I can't quite seem to get to it nor see whether it's actually useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To "get to" the formula you mention, use the law of total expectation:
$$
  \mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}_1]
= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[X \mid \mathcal{G}_2] \mid \mathcal{G}_1]
$$
for any random variable $X$ and any $\sigma$-fields $\mathcal{G}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{G}_2$. Apply this to $X=N(2)N(3)$ and $\mathcal{G}_1 = \sigma(N(2))$, $\mathcal{G}_2 = \mathcal{F}$ (the original $\sigma$-field for the space).

Next, to use this, note that 
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[N(3) \mid N(2)]
&= \mathbb{E}[N(0,2] + N(2,3]  \mid N(0,2]] \\
&= N(0,2] + \mathbb{E}[N(2,3]  \mid N(0,2]] \\
&= N(0,2] + \mathbb{E}[N(2,3] ] \\
\end{align}
because of independent increments. Therefore
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[N(2)N(3)]
&= \mathbb{E}[N(2)^2 + N(2)N(2,3]] \\
&= \mathbb{E}[N(2)^2] + \mathbb{E}[N(2)]\mathbb{E}[N(2,3]] \\
&= 2\lambda + (2\lambda)^2 + 2\lambda^2 \\
&= 2\lambda(3\lambda + 1). 
\end{align}

Answer (score 9):

Let$\ (0<s<t<\infty)$. Then, defintion of covariance yields
$$(1)\ \ \ \ cov(N_s,N_t) = E[(N_s)-E[N_s]) (N_t-E[N_t])]$$
For a Poisson process, $E[N_t]=\lambda t$, and $E[N_s]=\lambda s$
$$(2)\ \ \ cov(N_s,N_t) = E[(N_s-s\lambda)(N_t-t\lambda)]=E[N_sN_t]-s\lambda E[N_t]-t\lambda E[N_s]+st\lambda ^2=E[N_sN_t]-st\lambda ^2$$

Then,
$$(3)\ \ \ \ E[N_sN_t] = E[(N_t-N_s)(N_s-N_0)]+E[N_s^2]\ \ \ \ (since \ N_0=0)$$
Since $(0,s)$ and $(s,t)$ are disjoint and therefore independent
$$(4)\ \ \ \ E[N_sN_t] = E[(N_t-N_s)]E[(N_s-N_0)]+E[N_s^2]=\lambda ^2(t-s)s+E[N_s^2]=st\lambda ^2-s^2\lambda^2+E[N_s^2]$$
Subsititute the result of (4) into the equation in (2)
$$(5)\ \ \ \ cov(N_s,N_t)=-s^2\lambda^2+E[N_s^2]$$
Now, $E[X^2]=var(X)+E[X]^2$ for any random variable $X$
$$(6)\ \ \ cov(N_s,N_t)=-s^2\lambda ^2+var(N_s)+E[N_s]^2=-s^2\lambda^2 +s\lambda +s^2\lambda^2 = \lambda s$$
$$$$
You can see that if we had defined $t<s$, the two would switch in step (3), and we would end up with $cov(N_s,N_t) = \lambda t$.  So, we can say that the covariance function of a Poisson process in general is
$$R_N(s,t)=cov(N_s,N_t)=\lambda min\{s,t\}$$
So, I do think the answer to this question is $cov(N_2,N_3)=2\lambda$.

Comment: Please do not edit your answer to remove all content.  If you are unhappy with your answer for some reason, you can hit the little "delete" button and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Write ${\rm E}[N(3)N(2)]$ as
$$
{\rm E}[(N(3)-N(2))N(2)]+{\rm E}[N(2)^2]
$$
and use that $(N(t))_{t\geq 0}$ has independent increments.